# how to get the information out of the query

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7, healthkit

i have created a global variable to store the information

```
var stepsCount:Float = 0
```

and used it to store the number of steps inside the query

```
let stepsCountQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsCountType,quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .CumulativeSum, completionHandler: {
(query, results, error) in
if results == nil{
    print(error)
}
else {
    let info = results!.sumQuantity()
    if info == nil {
        print("no information available")
    }
    else {
        stepsCount = Float(info!.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit()))
    }
}
})
```

but it seems that the variable is not changing when excuse the query
any ideas??

Comment: Is the Query actually getting executed? Is the completion handler actually getting called?

Comment: yes it is because i tried to call a function (inside the query)that affects the UI and it worked but for some reason it can't change this variable

Comment: Have you tried break pointing inside the else to see what `info!.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit())` returns?

Comment: yes i did and it worked perfectly at getting the right number

Comment: Where are you checking the value of stepsCount? Is it triggered from within the completion block?

Comment: i am trying to use the value in the view controller class to put it on the screen
when i print it on the screen from within the query it self it worked but when i use a global variable the number never gets out the query

Comment: Can you include the entire code the puts the number on screen? Are you triggering the UI update on the `main_thread`? The queries always execute on a background thread.

Comment: i use this line 
    stepsTracker.setProgress(stepsCount/1300 , animated: true)

Comment: That line of code isn't helpful without the rest of the code. I'm concerned with what values you're setting on what UI objects and what thread it's happening on.

Comment: i am using that line inside the viewdidload function

Comment: I don't understand why you're not just posting the code. I can't tell where your query is being run from and I'm willing to bet that you've got the threading wrong. If you won't post more complete code no one can help you.

Comment: this is viewcontroller.swift file
import UIKit
import HealthKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var stepsTracker: UIProgressView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
if checkStore(healthStore){
healthStore.excuteQuery(stepsCountQuery)
stepsTracker.setProgress(stepsCount/1300 , animated: true)}

Comment: and this is another swift file that i have created
var stepsCount:Float = 0
let stepsCountQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsCountType,quantitySamplePredicate: predicat, options: .CumulativeSum, completionHandler: {(query, results, error) in if results == nil{
     print(error)
                    }else {
                        let info = results!.sumQuantity()
                        if info == nil {
                            print("no information available")
                        }else {
stepsCount = Float(info!.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit()))}} })

Answer (score 0):

Your completion block should look more like this:

```
let stepsCountQuery = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepsCountType,quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .CumulativeSum, completionHandler: { 
       (query, results, error) in
    if results == nil{
        print(error)
    }
    else {
         let info = results!.sumQuantity()
         if info == nil {
             print("no information available")
         }
         else {
             stepsCount = Float(info!.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.countUnit()))
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                   stepsTracker.setProgress(stepsCount/1300 , animated: true) 
              })
         }
    }
 })
```

Comment: should i put it inside the viewdidload function?

Comment: That's probably a fine place to put it.